# Prevent page break when using multicols at end of page

Tags: page-breaking, overleaf, multicolumn

I have a section with columns near the end of a page, and when compiling it breaks page. I'd like to keep my columns on the first page. How to do it ? Thanks

```
\section{Section}
\begin{multicols}{4}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item a
        \item b
        \item c
        \item d
    \end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
```

[image: compiled code]

Comment: Try `\enlargethispage{5em}` or a more suitable length.

Comment: @PeterWilson thanks! that worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

An extension to my comment. `\enlargethispage` can be helpful but unfortunately is not a universal panacea.

```
% enlargeprob.tex  SE 637686

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\enlargethispage{1\baselineskip}  %% extends text by one line
%\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}  %% extends text by two lines, bumping into the footer
%\enlargethispage{3\baselineskip}  %% extends text by three lines, overprinting the footer

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

While you are definitely not using a standard `\section`, with no MWE I had to make do (your mileage may vary).  Without special treatment, anything over `38\baselineskip` will force a page break.

The main problem is that multicols adds extra space before and after.  One way to remove these spaces it to put it into a minipage, which absorbs spaces at the top and bottom.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{39\baselineskip}

\section{Section}\everypar{}% disable \@afterheading
\hrule
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{multicols}{4}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item a
        \item b
        \item c
        \item d
    \end{itemize}
\end{multicols}\end{minipage}
\hrule

\end{document}
```